# Can I get a DVD version of Mazi en Gondolando somewhere?

Tags: learning

I really enjoyed Mazi, but it would be really neat to be able to buy it and use it at home like that.

Comment: What is *Mazi*? I assume a film?

Comment: @OliverMason https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCJt_Advj-A&list=LLnRmwsrEISCLAARhrWDjXQw&index=1

Answer (score 5):

It seems that there is only videotape of "Mazi en Gondolando" for sale. It's available for sale in [UEA](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=4838), which is actually two videotapes ("Mazi en Gondolando" and "Mazi revenas al Gondolando") and one book. It's also in the [library of IEI](https://web.archive.org/web/20180320095925/http://www.iei.nl/bibHOeo.htm) (Internacia Esperanto-Instituto).

---

Ŝajne nur videobendo de "Mazi en Gondolando" estas por vendo. Ĝi estas vendota de [UEA](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=4838), kiu estas fakte du videobendoj ("Mazi en Gondolando" kaj "Mazi revenas al Gondolando") kaj unu libro. Ĝi estas ankaŭ en la [biblioteko de IEI](https://web.archive.org/web/20180320095925/http://www.iei.nl/bibHOeo.htm) (Internacia Esperanto-Instituto).

Answer (score 1):

I had it once on Dvd I will try to talk to UEA or to IEI in Antwerp and see if they can bring it again on DVD
Mi iam havis ghin sur DVD kaj mi provos paroli al UEA au al IEI kaj vidi chu ili povas eldoni ghin denove. 
Mi vidis kelkajn lecionoj de ghi che Youtube kun subtitoloj.

Answer (score 1):

Mi trovis la tekston kaj ekzercojn en la portugala lingvo en chi tiu loko kiel PDF, Ghi komencas ek de la pagho 13

https://jornalggn.com.br/sites/default/files/documentos/esperanto_-_mazi_en_gondolando_-_livro_do_aluno_nova_versao-2.0-_atualizacao_16_abril_de_2010.pdf

Mi trovis ghin serchante " mazi en gondolando pdf "

Answer (score 0):

DVD de Mazi trovigxas en azenreto:
ed2k://|file|Mazi_1_Esperanto_Mazi_en_Gondolando_DVD_bildoj.zip|1676910812|E3E60A5C7252B434453CE6E86214A583|h=SP54NAVJ43UQXN4SSZDL2ZZH5J327WZU|/
ed2k://|file|Mazi_2_Esperanto_Mazi_revenas_al_Gondolando_DVD_bildoj.zip|1826635381|43F5999DDC27273B4F1244E516AABFB0|h=GIRCFHVTYQOB3W5V4STGC3JDFYJBAQOI|/

Comment: Is this copyrighted material?  If this is, please remove the answer as to not jeopardize the website.  Otherwise, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Karlomanio Either way I don’t think this answers the question because the OP was asking where they could buy a physical DVD if I understand correctly. If they just want a digital version it is easy to find on YouTube.

Comment: @NeilRoberts These are links to ISO's that would allow for easy creation of your own DVD's.

Comment: Apparently it’s not SE policy to try to police copyright infringements unless there is an official take down request so I’ve removed the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube yesterday (2019-06-25) removed Mazi 1-6 and is now displaying a text, saying that the video is violating the terms of use. This is strange as it has been there for a long time, and other language versions, such as English, Spanish, or Russian, are still available. Also the videos where Mazi comes back to Gondolando are still there.

Comment: welcome to Esperanto Language Stackexchange! Your contribution is useful, but it could be improved by including links to the mentioned videos. If you went a step further and made a list of the episodes and their availability, it would be great!